# Explicit data types in Antlr4

Tags: java, parsing, token, antlr4, abstract-data-type

i am new to Antlr and writing in java, and i am currently trying to figure out how i can make the parser identify the token "var" as either an int, string etc. Just as in javascript where you use either var or let. I am trying to make my own programming language which has explicit data types, so that it would be easier for a beginner to start coding, without worrying wether he/she is using an int/string/char and so on.

I dont seem to find any documentation for it online, so i am hoping that someone here can teach me in how i would make this possible

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really a task you'd accomplish directly with ANTLR.

ANTLR generates code to produce a Parser for you.  That means it will process your input and produce a data structure (a ParseTree in ANTLRs case), that correctly catagorizes all of your input (assuming it's syntactically correct; an error message otherwise).

In your case you'd have a ParseTree that would correctly identify that you have a `var` keyword, an Identifier (your variable name) an `=` and a value.  This would probably be the result of matching matching a parse rule for something like `assignmentStmt`.

With that ParseTree in memory, you'll have listener and/or visitor classes that ANTLR generates to make it quite easy to navigate that ParseTree.

With everything parsed out for you (by ANTLR), it would be up to you, in your own code to do the type inference (what you are describing is type inference rather than "explicit typing").  Or, if you're wanting to allow any type to be assigned to your variable, you really don't have any thing you need to do (You have a typeless language, and no need to verify types.  Your *runtime* would, of course, want to keep track of what the type of the currently assigned value is, but would allow assignment of a new value of any type.)

Antlr's job is to correctly identify all the parts according to your Syntax (Type *checking* is a Semantic concern, and not something the Parser concerns itself with).  It does not create Symbol Tables for you, or attempt to do type inference.  These are tasks that are up to you once the input is parsed.

Side note, JavaScript is untyped so, you just have a variable or constant, that can hold anything, there is no type (inferred, or explicit).

Explcit typing would be something like:

```
var myString : String;
```

Implcit typing would be something like:

```
var myVar = "String"
```

and you would have code that essentially says "They have assigned a String to `myVar` so, henceforth, `myVar` is a String type and will accept no value other than a String.

In JavaScript, you're just getting a variable, and you can turn right around as assign it a numeric value, an object, or anything you like (it's typeless).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response, i will look more into type inference!

Answer (score 0):

A parser is a tool to determine if certain input is syntactically correct and can convert the input to a specific data structure, if that's the case (as Mike Cargal explained). That means a parser is a tool to deal with the syntax of the input.

Specifying types and other meta information of the input is applying meaning to certain strings, which is commonly called semantic processing.

Knowing that a parser is a syntax tool should make clear that a parser cannot be used to apply semantics. It's important to differentiate between syntax and semantic, to understand which tool can do what.

How to apply semantics in the way you seem to want is a complete own topic and too broad to be handled in a single question.